# How to call function on click event in Jquery when the element is generated dynamically by script and access through class selector?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

**I am generating an anchor tag through script with class 'section-delete-btn' :**

```js
<a class='section-delete-btn' role='button' id = '" + $("#section_name").val() + "'href='#'><i class='section-delete-btns fa fa-trash-o' aria-hidden='true'></i></a>
```

**I am trying to access the a tag through class selector like this :**

```js
//delete a section
$('a').on('click','.section-delete-btn',function(){
  //get section name
  var section_name = $(this).attr('id');
  alert(section_name);
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are already using a delegate listener, but it will fail if, at the time of attaching the listener, your document does not have any `a` elements. Instead, use `document`:

```
$(document).on('click','a.section-delete-btn',function(){
  //get section name
  var section_name = $(this).attr('id');
  alert(section_name);
});
```

Comment: Hey it worked, can you forward me some resources where I can read more about this concept?

Comment: Google `delegate listener jquery`.